# Ubuntu sftp chroot jail on usb folder

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sftp

I have a problem configuring the sftp chroot jail on ubuntu on a folder that is stored on a usb.
I have a toshiba 4tb external hard disk, that it's automounted via **fstab** on */sftp* path.

```
UUID={UUID} /sftp ext4 auto,defaults,nofail,rw 0 0
```

I have followed all the necessary steps to configure the sftp jail

```
sudo groupadd sftponly

sudo useradd -g sftponly -s /bin/false -m -d /sftp/backupsftp backupsftp

sudo passwd backupsftp

sudo chown root: /sftp/backupsftp

sudo chmod 755 /sftp/backupsftp

sudo mkdir /sftp/backupsftp/backup

sudo chmod 755 /sftp/backupsftp/backup

sudo chown backupsftp:sftponly /sftp/backupsftp/backup
```

Then added to the bottom of the **/etc/ssh/sshd_config** file

```
Match Group sftponly
  ChrootDirectory %h
  ForceCommand internal-sftp
  AllowTcpForwarding no
  X11Forwarding no
Match all
```

and setted the following value (always in **/etc/ssh/sshd_config** file):

```
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp
Port 22
AddressFamily inet
ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
PermitRootLogin no
StrictModes yes
```

Finally i have restarted the services:

```
sudo systemctl restart ssh
sudo systemctl restart sshd
```

When i try to connect with WinScp i get this error:
[screenshot error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mW2sx.png)

Everything **works correctly** if the **home directory** of the user created resides on the main disk and not on the usb